# Has the Mathematica V12.2 rollout been delayed?

Tags: discussion

It has now been several weeks since the release of V12.2. However, when I log in to the Wolfram Portal (institutional account) I find only 12.1.1 of Mathematica for Sites available. I am aware of some major bugs in 12.2 (DSolve, CUDA, etc), and wonder whether the rollout has been delayed till these are fixed. Are others finding that 12.2 is unavailable to them too?

I have been using Mathematica since V1.0 and do not recall a similar delay.

Comment: I just logged into the Wolfram User Portal. It shows only 12.1.1, but over on the far right there is a link labeled "Free Upgrade" that takes me to a page which offers 12.2.0. Do you not see this link?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. No, I do not see such a link. However, I am content to stick with  12.1.1 for now, as some of the reported bugs in 12.2 might be an issue for me. I will wait.